# async-await "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error - in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In this line `DispatchQueue.main.async` I get this error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
import Foundation

class ProductListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var productList = [Product]()
    let webService = WebService()
    
    func downloadData(url: URL) async {
        
        do {
            let product = try await webService.getData(url: url)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.productList = product.map(ProductViewModel.init)
            }
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}

struct ProductViewModel {
    
    let productModel: Product
    var id: Int {
        productModel.id
    }
    var title: String {
        productModel.title
    }
    var price: Double {
        productModel.price
    }
    var description: String {
        productModel.description
    }
    var category: Category {
        productModel.category
    }
    var imageUrl: String {
        productModel.imageUrl
    }
    var rating: Rating {
        productModel.rating
    }
}

struct WebService {
    
    func getData(url: URL) async throws -> [Product] {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        let product = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Product].self, from: data)
        return product ?? []
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code, not pictures of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers

Comment: ok i'm sorry. I edited

Comment: Show us WebService. Show us ProductViewModel. Show us `productList`. There should be _no unknowns_ in the code you show us. Please read about how to supply a [mcve].

Comment: thank you for advise. i am new user and programmer. i will learn steakoverflow

Comment: You did great in the end! Well done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error (which is admittedly nondescriptive and unhelpful here) is because you're trying to set `[ProductViewModel]` (which is what your `map` returns) to `productList` which is of the type `[Product]`.

`ProductViewModel` doesn't seem to have a purpose here -- it's just an identical wrapper around product. You can change your code inside the `do` block to this:

```
let products = try await webService.getData(url: url)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.productList = products
}
```

To further refactor, you should annotate your `ProductListViewModel` with `@MainActor` to ensure its properties get set on the main queue and then you can get rid of the `DispatchQueue.main.async` call -- the new `async/await` API doesn't mix well with `DispatchQueue` and vice versa.

```
@MainActor class ProductListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var productList = [Product]()
    let webService = WebService()
    
    func downloadData(url: URL) async {
        do {
            let products = try await webService.getData(url: url)
            self.productList = products
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a pity that sometimes the compiler still just waves its hands over this kind of type mismatch. I recommend that the OP submit this as a bug report to Apple; they _do_ want to improve their error messages, and they have done a lot of work already to make them better, so they definitely want to hear about cases like this.

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote this twice, as you gave two very penetrating pieces of advice. :) I would just advise that you remove "you can" — you mean "you must". Using `async/await` means you _must not_ use DispatchQueue; they do not play well together.

Comment: @matt thanks -- I appreciate the kind words. Regarding the `DispatchQueue`, I will add an edit. However, as an interesting technical point, although I agree that there is some potentially unexpected behavior trying to mix `DispatchQueue` and `async/await`, I *think* that in this case it would still technically work as expected, correct? I know that the opposite (trying to force a `DispatchQueue` to use `@MainActor`) won't work.